# Dual-Boot Partition Format Concerns

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

Sorry if duplicate --
I may want, in the future, to install Windows alongside Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on the same HDD.  I'm afraid that if I need to reformat a partition or create a new one, I'll mess up my Ubuntu and have to reinstall it, which would be a big headache.  Is there a sure way to avoid screwing up the existing Ubuntu partitions?  I've already messed it up once by reformatting the *unused space* partition (got the dreaded GRUB prompt). [My current partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOkR7.png)

Comment: your partitioning system seems nice. how would you like to have windows partitions? C Drive + Some More Partitions? in your partitions i saw you have allocated [960GB FAT] i think you need to make it as NTFS file format before installing the windows. I suggest you to go through the Q&A about installing windows after Ubuntu as windows will kill GRUB in your case.

Comment: Yes, I fully expect GRUB to be messed up, as that's been my experience ever since I built this new PC.  As to NTFS, that is precisely what I wanted it to be, but I didn't see NTFS as an option during the partitioning process.  It's always something.  Thanks.

Comment: have you tried making it from GParted? try to access 960GB FAT partition from GParted and format it to NTFS and then boot with windows to see if it is showing in installation time. which version of windows you want to install?

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid buying Windows by installing the old HDD with Vista already on it.  But if that doesn't work and I somehow convince myself to give Micro$oft too much money, then it'll be either Win 7 or Win 10.  Are you pretty sure using GParted to reformat will not mess up the GRUB or bootloader or whatever?  I've regretted my actions before.

Comment: Yes i am sure. Here we are touching only Partition No. 4 which is 960GB. if you are unsure, try directly booting with windows installation USB and check if it is showing the partition with 960GB FAT at this stage. if you dont see this 960GB Partition then go to GParted and format it to NTFS and do the Install. By the way are you going to keep 960GB for Windows C Drive or you want some more partitions?

Comment: I guess I would want a new partition just for Windows and then to have the rest remain as empty or unallocated space for use as NTFS.  I've installed Wine and PlayOnLinux and I'll be testing certain Windows programs -- and, who knows, maybe I'll decide I don't need any Windows after all.  That'd be cool.

Comment: OK if you decide to install windows make around 100 to 200gb out of 960gb as Ntfs by GParted and leave the remaining unallocated.

Comment: I appreciate the advice.